# Is there a way to get only the first key of a dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

## I am trying to get the first key of a dictionary with the following standards

#### I have tried to retrieve it by doing this:

```
label = {"D_00001":["blue","white"],
         "D_00002":["pink","brown"]}

list = []
for key in label.keys(): 
    list.append(key[0])
```

#### but I am only getting the first letter of the key that is "D"

#### I want to access only the first key in a specif way.

Comment: `next(iter(label))`

Answer (score 5):

You can simply take the first key like this:

```
label = {"D_00001":["blue","white"],
         "D_00002":["pink","brown"]}

>>> k = list(label.keys())[0]
>>> k
'D_00001'
```

which will give you a possibly arbitrary key (depending on Python version). There is no concept of the first key in a dictionary, although recent versions of Python 3 preserve the order of insertion into the dict.

Perhaps you could sort the keys first?

```
>>> k = sorted(label)[0]
>>> k
'D_00001'
```